# SpecialCell(xlCellTypeLastCell) does not work in custom function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

The custom function below entered in a cell with a reference to another cell does not work. I do not understand why. Does anybody know the answer?

```
Public Function SpecialCellBroken(rng As Range)
Debug.Print rng.Worksheet.Cells.Address
Debug.Print rng.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

SpecialCellBroken = rng.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
End Function
```

Return in debug window:

```
$1:$1048576
$1:$1048576
```

However, the following Sub works fine and returns the address of the last cell:

```
Sub SpecialCellWorksFine()
    Debug.Print Selection.Worksheet.Cells.Address
    Debug.Print Selection.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

    Selection.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
End Sub
```

Return in debug window:

```
$1:$1048576
$J$21
```

Also referencing from the range to the worksheet with `Parent` does not work.
Tried `ByVal` on the parameter `rng`. Also no effect to the better.
Any suggestions what is the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: SpecialCells does not work in a UDF().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` Wont work in a UDF as UDFs cannot interact with Excel (Or the program you are using at that time). What you can do though is:

```
Sub SpecialCellWorksFine()
x = Selection.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address(False, False)

n = y(x)

End Sub

Public Function y(x As String)
'Code goes here
End Function
```

This has been simplified but the principal is the same, you assign what values you want to go into the UDF *before* you call it and then pull the ones you want into the UDF (The limit I believe is 30)